# Java: Combining the inputs of a while loop

Tags: java, loops, input, while-loop

How can i combine the inputs below a **while loop**?

---

```
 try {
  System.out.println("Keep selecting the ingrients that you want until you                 press (0)");
  int ingrientsID = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  while (!"0".equals(ingrientsID )) {
  System.out.println("One more?");
  ingrientsID = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  if (ingrientsID == 0) {
  break; 
  } 
  }
```

Comment: `while (!"0".equals(ingrientsID ))`? first whats your problem

Comment: please clarify the question. what do you want to do with the inputs? do you add, subtract, multiply, etc....

Comment: Your question is not clear... its already doing what's intended to do

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear what you're asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: i want to combine each input that i type in here

Comment: "combine" means "concatenation" or "addition"? As you are trying to read `Integer`, it seems addition to me, which should be pretty simple.

Comment: Use array instead of integer to get values

Comment: @thanga and how can i do the addition of these values?

Comment: @Fadel,I posted the answer with some comments on the code, please don't forget to click on the check mark if I answered your question.

Comment: @triForce420 thanks for answering my question and fixing that "one more" thingy!

Comment: @triForce420 i'm a newbie actually and that's why i couldn't explain my problem clearly :D

Comment: ahh, that's ok :) 

I actually removed the "one more" thingy since it's just redundant ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code together with some comments.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
//import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ingredients {

    public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        //or Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ingredientID=0;
        int sumOfIngredients=0;


        System.out.println("Keep selecting the ingrients that you want until you press (0)");

        //use do while to make it run at least once
        do{
            //get input, add to sumofIngredients
            ingredientID=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        //or ingredientID= scan.nextInt(); if you're using scanner

            //add the ingredient
            sumOfIngredients+=ingredientID;

       //I don't think you need to ask "one more?". 
//You have given the instruction (to keep selecting the ingredients till the user presses 0 )
        }while(ingredientID!=0);

            //print the ingredients!
        System.out.println("sum of ingredients: "+ sumOfIngredients);           
    }
}
```

Please don't forget to use the "homework" tag next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do the following:

```
int ingrientsID = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
while (ingrientsID != 0) {
    System.out.println("One more?");
    ingrientsID = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    // no breaks needed for ingrientsID == 0 as loop condition will 
    // automatic stop iterate for ingrientsID == 0
    // do more stuffs
}
```

Comment: you forgot to add the ingredients :/

Answer (score 0):

```
  boolean flag=true;

  System.out.println("Keep selecting the ingrients that you want until you                 press (0)");
  int ingrientsID = 0,temp=0;
  while (flag) {//until user enters 0  
  temp=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  ingrientsID += temp;//to sum each input that you type
  if (temp==0) {//is user enters 0 then
  flag=false;
  }
  else
  System.out.println("One more?"); 
}
System.out.println("sum: "+ingrientsID);//final result
```